# Azure - Best practice to scale a single thread app based on pending items

Tags: azure

In the past we have built our system using a stateless service infrastructure where as we have a front end API that puts items into an Azure queue, then there were worker roles processing these queues.  On paper, this looked great, and how the cloud should work. As our queue grew, it would spin up more instances of our app, which is single threaded and each handled a batch of 30 items.  As the queue shrank, it would spin them down.

This however ended up not working as expected.  Azure only auto scaled Worker based on items in queue, not items pending. And since items could be put into our queue up to 5 days in advance, this left us with a ton of scaled instances we did not need.  As a solution, we ended up just keeping our instances scaled to what we needed at most, which sort of took away from the whole cloud experience. Also, as we got bursts of data, we sometimes got backed up. We ideally want our data processed in seconds, but it was taking minutes since it could only handle so much at once with this methodology.

Due to the nature of how cloud services spin up and down, this was not only costly, but when we needed to really add resources, we had to wait 10+ minutes for our instances to spin up.  That is with us manually watching the queues and adjusting the instances in azure. I know we can develop a 3rd party app to auto spin up and down, but the real issue is how long it takes to simply add or remove a single instance.

Because of all of the restrictions we were running into with Cloud Services, we ended up resorting back to a single application that can handle adding 150+ individual threads, and each reports progress back to the main UI.  For a fraction of the cost, and almost no system power, we went from having 40 instances running in cloud services at all times, to having up to 150 threads running at any time, auto scaling up and down as we seen fit.  We simply look at whats going to come up in the next 3 minutes and scale our threads based on that.

This single app scaling up and down works perfectly, just as I would like to happen in the cloud. We are seeing performance like never before, i can see the state of all threads at once, and it is very low overhead, since each thread handles a batch of 30 in queue items, and each tasks takes about 2-3 seconds.

Now the obvious downfall is we are basically reverting back to the old way of thinking and the cloud infrastructure we are utilizing is nothing more than a virtual machine. What if this one app crashes or computer restarts?  What happens when we need more processing power?  How do we easily deploy a single WinForm app running? (We use octopus deploy and it does only windows services)  How do we deal with maybe 8 different EXE's all running on a desktop?

We know there has to be a better way, where we can scale a single thread automatically based on our current workload. Also where this runs in the cloud so we are not restricted by managing VMs.

I spent a good 6 hours reading on service fabric, and it seems like a great step in the right direction, however I still cannot find a single document that covers our use case and the best way to go about setting this up.

How do i make a system that auto scales instances of a single task (thread) as it needs, and when each task is done, decide if it should spin down because it is no longer needed?  I know I will need a parent worker that spins these instances up, and tells each if it needs to shut down when complete. However I cannot find any examples coding / documents of a project like this, that utilizes azure.

A great use case would be an email sender:
 - We have an application that puts emails into a queue with a schedule of when to go out.
 - We have a second single threaded app that pulls the next 30 items in queue, ready to go, and sends them out.
 - Now what happens when someone adds 25,000 items into queue right now?
   We want the emails to go out when they should, but how do we scale
   this single, 1 threaded app, to have multiple instances.  How do we
   then scale down the threads no longer needed once complete?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at `Azure Functions`? From what I understand, you don't have to worry about scaling the infrastructure yourself.

Comment: I started to this week, just like I did service fabric.  I still am at the core problem of how do i scale out a single instances based on my workload (queue)?   Scaling a VM based on usage is easy, but how do we auto start / then shut down the tasks not needed?

Comment: I have read briefly about Azure Functions and from what I have understood is that you don't have to worry about it. It essentially provides a server-less infrastructure (much like Amazon Lambda) which scales up/down automatically based on the workload. Unless you need access to underlying VM, I would strongly recommend taking a look at it and see if this is something that you can use: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-functions/.

Comment: I remember now why i stopped looking at this.  All of the docs said that a trigger can happen when an item is added to queue, which I would need it to trigger when the time expiration is up in the queue, not just when added.  I would imagine that is what they mean but also would have though azure web services would auto scale based on items ready to send in queue, not the total count of items in queue regardless of if they are not ready to send for 5 more days.

Will look further into it though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't about how to scale infrastructure, but is how you architect your activity workflow.  If you only want the queue to be processed at a specific time (when its going to expire), and not when it's added, have you thought about adding a secondary queue which is your current workload, as opposed to the queued future workload?

Then just move the items from the pending queue to the "active" queue when you want them to be consumed.  At that point you can then rely on instance scaling to consume the workload from the active queue.  The platform you use for consuming the workload then is your choice - functions, web jobs, batch, etc;  You could use logic apps however to help coordinate the worklflow piece and move messages between queues.

Comment: Russell, 

We actually do this now, as we constantly need stuff to go in the far future and there is a limitation of I believe 7 days in Azure Queues.  However the issue still arose of scaling the queue.  Using Cloud Services just did not work because it took far to long to scale a single instance.  When a message needs to go now (aka its ready to go in queue), I need it to send now, not in 5-10 mins when it finally scales the new instances up.  Ideally though the new features such as Functions will run a lot quicker.

Comment: I still need a worker setup just to process the queues, but moving data from one to another is likely extremely fast so just having a separate app for that would probably work.  But correct, that is exactly what I am looking for. A way to reliably instance scale. Going to continue to research Functions and hopefully it works a lot better than Cloud Services did.  Thanks.

Comment: App Services and Functions will scale much quicker than Cloud services yes - since the containers are already built and ready to go - with CS your VM has to be provisioned and deployed and spun up.  Although this is getting faster, it wont be as quick as app services/functions.

Comment: ps. you could look at ServiceBus as well instead of storage queues.  ServiceBus can act as a messagebroker - it's a more expensive than storage queues but doesn't have the 7 day ttl restriction.

Comment: Yeh we looked into it before and did not move to them simply due to having a worker that moves from a long wait queue to real queue was pretty simple addition.  Thanks for all the feedback!